# htaccess to hide Joomla in public_html -> subfolder

Tags: joomla-3.x, .htaccess-configuration

I installed Joomla using a quickstart package and store the files in a subfolder (named: jml) in public_html/jml. I normally use the following commands to rewrite the url from https://www.test.com/jml to https://www.test.com/ (to hide the "jml"). It works correctly with new Joomla installation, but with this quickstart package it can only  hide the folder named "jml" for backend (https://www.test.com/administrator) but not the frontend as it will still show https://www.test.com/jml/ even though all settings have been set accordingly. I'm not sure which file I need to check and not very familiar with htaccess. Can you advise how to fix this issue? Could it be file permission? Thanks

Settings: 
- Use URL Rewriting (enabled)
- live_site (https://www.test.com)
- RewriteBase / (enabled)
- cpanel doesn't have the feature to set root folder.

### htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^test.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.test.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !jml/
RewriteRule (.*) /jml/$1 [L]
```

---

Answer (score 1):

I use pretty much the same code for most of my sites and to make it work I have to hard code the site domain into the livesite variable in configuration.php. You cannot check or change it through the Global Configuration of your Administrator area.

You need to login to your hosting account and go to the root directory of your site, in this case /jml and have a look at the $livesite= in configuration.php and perhaps compare it to your site that is working.

It should be `$livesite='https://www.test.com',` in my experience.

Comment: Yes. The configuration.php has already been set to $live_site='https://www.test.com' and it works correctly for all my other websites but not this quickstart package. I'm unsure where else I can check and fix this issue. I talked to quickstart developer and they told me it has nothing to do with them because it is related to Joomla core.

Comment: In the default .htaccess that should be in your //jml folder does it have  RewriteBase commented or un-commeted and if it is the latter does it have a folder name or /.